# Конкурс. Имеет ли смысл?

Tags: дефект, вопросы, конкурс

Я задал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1106049/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-dom-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0), который заминусовали

Но я не получил практически никаких веских доводов против предложенных решений. Я бы хотел получить больше информации, создав конкурс. Но я боюсь, что у меня будет -1000. Можно ли это оценить? Насколько это реально?

Comment: Конкурс не гарантирует, что будет дан ответ, причем даже если ответ будет дан, возможно он тебя не устроит, но репутацию за конкурс уже будет не вернуть

Comment: @Grundy это не проблема. Я это понимаю. Меня больше волнует 100500 минусов.

Comment: Ну от минусов никто застраховать не может, но как правило основная часть появляется в первое время. При конкурсе вряд ли будет много, плюс есть вероятность, что кому-то вопрос понравится и даже будет плюсовая компенсация :)

Comment: @Grundy можно ли будет удалить вопрос, чтобы минусы не плодились?

Comment: Его можно будет всегда удалить после конкурса

Comment: @Grundy Так конкурс 7 дней идёт (=

Comment: ну и что? :) репутация все равно восстановится, ну кроме конкурсной на сколько я понимаю

Comment: Восстановится? Как же?

Comment: при удалении вопроса/ответа репутация полученная за него откатывается

Comment: @Grundy _Его можно будет всегда удалить после конкурса_ - достаточно одного ответа с плюсом и ТС не сможет удалить вопрос. Разве не так?

Comment: @0xdb, резонное замечание, но решается обращением к модераторам :)

Comment: @Grundy Но они могут не согласится, это смотря кто ответит и сколько плюсов получит.

Comment: @0xdb, как правило с этой стороны проблем не возникает

Comment: @Grundy модераторы не удаляют вопросы, на которые даны ответы. Это будет некрасиво по отношению к автору ответа. Мы можем сделать дизассоциацию вопроса.

Comment: @0xdb не важно кто и сколько плюсов, важен сам факт того, что мы таким образом обнуляем затраченные усилия автора ответа.

Comment: Я понял, что для меня это может оказаться крайне опасная ситуация. Я могу получить минус очень большой рейтинг. Видимо, я этим не буду заниматься. Спасибо

Comment: @hedgehogues, вряд ли намного больше чем сейчас :) тем более уже и плюсы появились.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, вполне могут и удалить

Comment: @Grundy ну, собственно, в ближайшее время я сделаю релиз гошной либки с детальным описанием кейсов. Мне она сильно помогает в парсинге товаров. Тут, конечно, вопрос, нафига мы мои коллеги стали юзать golang, вместо bs4 на питоне. Но это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: @Grundy другие возможно. Я удалю только если и автор ответа будет согласен.

Comment: @Grundy там 3 голоса за закрытие. Может, его ещё закроют (=

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik спасибо за переоткрытие

Comment: @hedgehogues закрывашки что-то совсем разошлись последнее время.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, что за модераторский произвол? :) зачем было голоса сбрасывать?

Comment: @Grundy чтобы не закрыли. Я подустал уже от этой мании всё позакрывать.

Comment: @hedgehogues По моему простейшее на данный момент удалить вопрос и задать новый, более конкретный вопрос, с учётом обсуждения в комментариях.

Comment: Пока что я поставил вашему вопросу минус - за неправильное название и метки. Из благих побуждений. Сам не умею правильно задавать вопросы.